# MySQL Sub Query takes long time to respond

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've created 3 tables imei, post and view. I've some 1000 records in all the 3 tables. Now when I execute the b/m query, it tooks very long to respond.

Table design & sample data are given below:

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imei` (
  `imei_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imei_no` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `imei_net` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imei_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `imei_no` (`imei_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1346 ;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
  `post_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_title` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `post_desc` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `post_author` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Admin',
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=876 ;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `view` (
  `view_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imei_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`view_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `imei_id` (`imei_id`,`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13706 ;
```

---

Values Inside table:

IMEI:

```
INSERT INTO `imei` (`imei_id`, `imei_no`, `imei_net`, `date`) VALUES
(1, '123456789012345', 'Airtel', '2015-08-06 07:39:47'),
(2, '234567890123456', 'Aircel', '2015-08-06 06:08:33')
```

POST:

```
INSERT INTO `post` (`post_id`, `post_title`, `post_desc`, `post_author`, `user_id`, `date`) VALUES
    (1, 'NSC Rate Down', 'NSC rates are getting down from today', 'Admin', 1, '2015-07-08 05:29:54'),
    (2, 'NCDEX offers cashback', 'NCDEX offers cashback for the previous users', 'Admin', 1, '2015-07-08 05:30:01')
```

VIEW:

```
INSERT INTO `view` (`view_id`, `post_id`, `imei_id`, `status`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 1, '1', '1', '2015-08-08 05:04:38'),
(7, 2, '1', '1', '2015-08-08 07:55:25')
```

Query to Execute:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            i.imei_id,
            i.imei_no,
            p.post_id,
            p.post_title,
            p.post_desc,
            p.date,
            1 AS STATUS
        FROM
            imei i,
            post p,
            VIEW v
        WHERE
            i.imei_id = v.imei_id
        AND p.post_id = v.post_id
        AND i.imei_no = 356554064098771
        UNION
            SELECT
                i.imei_id,
                i.imei_no,
                p.post_id,
                p.post_title,
                p.post_desc,
                p.date,
                0 AS STATUS
            FROM
                imei i,
                post p
            WHERE
                i.imei_no = 356554064098771
            AND p.post_id NOT IN (
                SELECT
                    v.post_id
                FROM
                    imei i,
                    post p,
                    VIEW v
                WHERE
                    p.post_id = v.post_id
                AND v.imei_id = (
                    SELECT
                        i.imei_id
                    FROM
                        imei i
                    WHERE
                        imei_no = 356554064098771
                )
            )
    ) AS temp
WHERE
    date >= DATE_SUB(
        (
            SELECT
                date
            FROM
                imei
            WHERE
                imei_no = 356554064098771
        ),
        INTERVAL 1 WEEK
    )
ORDER BY
    date DESC
```

---

Comment: what do you expect as result?

Comment: Pls also include the results of the explain.

Comment: I'm getting proper result, but it takes more time as i'm using "not in" condition. I need an alternate solution

Comment: This query seems overly complicated to me and I do not think it makes sense. In the 2nd query of the union you select from all 3 tables, but in the where criteria you only join 2 (post and view), therefore the join with imei table becomes a carthesian join, so for every record in the imei table you get every record of the join of the other 2 tables.

Comment: @Lijibals raw sample data, expected results, and verbal description of what you want to achive is important for us to understand your query. Without these it will be difficult to provide you with an alternate solution. Your query seems overcomplicated.

Comment: I want to list the data in the b/m format
post_id | post_title | post_desc | date   | status

Answer (score 0):

try this query SELECT `post_id`,`post_title`,`post_desc`,`date`,if((`post_id` in (SELECT `post_id` FROM `view` WHERE `imei_id` = (SELECT `imei_id` FROM `imei` WHERE `imei_no`=865645026396909))),1,0) as status FROM `post`

Comment: This query is working good! Load time reduced from 0.4 to 0.05. If possible optimize it further to reduce load time, thanks for the code.